# Does $(x*w)$ denote the resulting composite function, given $*$ denotes the convolution operation?

Tags: notation

[Chapter 9.1](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) of the Deep Learning book gives this formula

$s(t)=(x*w)(t) \tag{(9.2)}$

where the operator $*$ denotes the convolution operation.

I'm conscious what the convolution operation is, I just have difficulty understanding the notation.

Does $(x*w)$ denote the resulting composite function which takes $t$ as its independent variable?

Here is the page in question

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x * w$ denotes the function that is the convolution of the functions $x$ and $w$. You can choose any letter for the independent variable. If you choose $t$, then it is written $(x * w)(t)$.

Comment: Thank you. Does the original $x$ denote a function or a set of numbers?

Comment: @JakeMZ It's apparently a real-valued function. It might be confusing when the author says $x, t$ are real-valued.