# Does it make sense to consider an image to be a function?

Tags: terminology

I'm learning the [Chapter 9.1](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) of the Deep Learning book.

Per post [Does $(x*w)$ denote the resulting composite function, given $*$ denotes the convolution operation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230778/929413), I guess I could consider $I*K$ a composite function, which means that $I$ is a function.

The book uses $I$ to denote a two-dimensional image, which leads to the image is being considered a function, does it make sense?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it *not* make sense?

It is standard (and useful) in signal processing to consider a quantity that varies over time, whether it is voltage, air pressure or light intensity, as a function $t \mapsto f(t)$ where $t$ is time. Not only is this a natural way of modelling a physical phenomenon, it also gives you all the mathematical tools that functions offer (convolution being just one example).

Here you are just considering an image as a function $(x,y) \mapsto I(x,y)$ that tells you how pixel intensity (or something) varies when you move in $x$ and $y$ directions. The reasons for treating it as a function are similar to the one-dimensional case.

The $*$ is not [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) but [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), just like the text says.